# How to pass user activity to GA with Googe-App-Scripts on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets

I stumbled upon this code from @igrigorik (https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon).

```
function sendGAMP(tid, url) {
  var payload = {
    'v': '1',
    'tid': tid,
    'cid': generateUUID_(),
    'z': Math.floor(Math.random()*10E7),
    't': 'pageview',
    'dl': url
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': payload
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', options);
}
```

The code works perfectly when fired from an onOpen function from the editor such as:

```
function onOpen(){
  sendGAMP("UA-YOUCODEHERE-X", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName());
}
```

I am trying to capture activity when a user opens a Google Spreadsheet published as a webpage without success.

Which type of function can I use to make sure that sendGAMP is triggered when the user opens the file? Clicks on the file? Is it possible at all due to restrictions about firing JavaScript from Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

> Which type of function can I use to make sure that sendGAMP is triggered when the user opens the file?

No joy - the `onOpen()` trigger is linked to the Sheets web GUI only, and no other form of "opening" a Spreadsheet will invoke a trigger function.

> ...clicks on the file?

Not sure what you mean by "file" here. If they can see the Sheet in Google Drive, and open it *online, on the web*, that will invoke an `onOpen()` trigger, as above.

#### Possible work-around

Write a Google Apps Script web app to serve your spreadsheet contents, for example as JSON data via the [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content). Then the web app would take care of kicking `sendGAMP()` to kick your analytics stats.